# How do I Change the Position of Golang Struct Values?

Tags: arrays, json, go, struct

How would I change the position of the json values?

What Im trying to achieve:

```
[{"key":"f","value":"f"},{"value":"f","key":"f"}]
```

Problem:

```
type Struct struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

func main() {
    test := []Struct{ {Key: "test",Value: "wep"}, {Value: "wep",Key: "test"}}


    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(test)
    fmt.Print(string(bytes))
}
```

Running this code prints `[{"key":"test","value":"wep"},{"key":"test","value":"wep"}]`

I have also tried doing something like this but it just printed empty values

```
type Struct struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Value2 string `json:"value"`
    Key2   string `json:"key"`
}
```

But how would I be able to switch the position of the key and value field around?

Comment: Why would you ever care about the order? That's a job for when you print it out. Not something that should be reflected in the data itself.

Comment: The reason I care about the order of the fields is because I'm trying to send json to a api. Which for some reason uses this weird format to specify what exactly the values are.

Comment: What wierd format? JSON is probably the most standard format when talking to an API over http, and it never cares about order of the fields.

Comment: Hi, with weird I mean that the api I'm using requires you to care about the order of the fields, to specify what the json values are for

Comment: That's doesn't sound like a wierd format, that sounds like something is broken on the API side. I would talk to the people who made it and inform them that they have a bug. (If it's not a bug, it's still a really really bad idea and something they should fix).

Comment: Yep, I was also wondering why they needed this format. But for now Il just have to work with this format. Anyways Il contact them now

Comment: (`[I'll] contact them now` please come back with the result.)

Comment: They responded to me saying it was a mistake on their part and that they will fix it, but it seems like after a few days nothing has changed so I'l still have to use this format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```golang
type StructA struct {
    Key   string `json:"key"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type StructB struct {
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Key   string `json:"key"`
}

func main() {
    test := []interface{}{
        StructA{Key: "test", Value: "wep"},
        StructB{Value: "wep", Key: "test"},
    }

    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(test)
    fmt.Print(string(bytes))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/72TWDU1BMaL

Answer (score 1):

To the question "can I make a single struct type serialize its fields in a different order or different occasions ?" :
there isn't a simple way to do this.

Regarding struct fields : the code you write shows the assigning operations in a given order, but once your code is compiled, there is no trace of that order anymore.

If you *really* need this (side note : I would be curious to know about your use case ?), you could create a custom type, with its own [`.MarshalJSON()`](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Marshaler) method, which would hold a value indicating "fields should be serialized in this order".

---

If what you need is to send an array of heterogeneous objects, use separate struct types, and an `[]interface{}` array :

```
type Obj1 struct{
    Key string `json:"name"`
    Value string `json:"value"`
}

type Obj2 struct{
    Value string `json:"value"`
    Key string `json:"name"`
}

func main() {
    test := []interface{}{ Obj1{Key: "test",Value: "wep"}, Obj2{Value: "wep",Key: "test"}}


    bytes, _ := json.Marshal(test)
    fmt.Print(string(bytes))
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/TOk28gL0eSK

Comment: Hi, thanks for the explanation on why it doesn't exactly work. Now I seem to understand the problem a bit better, the reason I need a json like this is to send data to a api ( which for some reason requires  this weird format). Also how would I create a custom type that would so something like this?

Comment: ouch, I feel for you. Just to confirm : sending `[{"key":"f","value":"f"},{"key":"f","value":"f"}]` or `[{"value":"f","key":"f"},{"value":"f","key":"f"}]` to that API doesn't work as expected ?

Comment: Hi, sending the data that way won't work as for some reason they need the order of the values to specify what the value is for.

Comment: Hi, yes I have tried this earlier and it didn't work. It could also be a bug in their api or something, not really sure why they require this.

Comment: are the fields actually `key, value`, or are they something else ? e.g : if `type` is `NPC`, then the following fields should be `name, skills, weapon`, if it is `monster`, they should be `weapon, skills, name` ...

Answer (score 1):

If you're using `json.Marshal` provided by official package it's not passible to do that. In stead, you can implement your own `MarhalJSON` method so that you can decide the position of your struct fields.